# Vue.js: How to bind key in name input attribute

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need "repositories[][name]" to be left with the key value "repositories[key][name]" to group the values when the form is submitted.

I can't find a way to add the key value. How can I do this function?

```
<tr v-for="(repository, key) in options.repositories">
<td><input type="text" name="repositories[][name]"
           :value="repository.name"
           class="form-control">
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="repositories[][url]"
           :value="repository.url"
           class="form-control">
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="repositories[][type]"
           :value="repository.type"
           class="form-control">
</td>
```

EDIT: I need the three values of the image to be grouper with the value "key"

[image]

For exemple in this case:

repositories[key] = [name => 'Product Grid', url => '...', type => 'vcs']

For this I need the value "key" to be printed in html.

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `:name="repositories[key][name]"`?

Comment: Whats the data structure of `options.repositories`? Can you please update that in your ques with an eg mock ds?

Comment: @ShivamSingh I have updated the main post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

To bind you only need to use `:` like this:

```html
    <tr v-for="(repository, key) in options.repositories">
    <td><input type="text" :name="repositories[key][name]"
               :value="repository.name"
               class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" :name="repositories[key][url]"
               :value="repository.url"
               class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" :name="repositories[key][type]"
               :value="repository.type"
               class="form-control">
    </td>
```

Comment: But this functionality does not print the value "key" to me in the html. I have updated the main post with an example.